# Is there any logical interpretation for why ${n-1 \choose k-1}/{n \choose k} = k/n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This showed up in a combinatorics problem, where we needed to find the probability of someone being on a team or not - hence the $n-1$ and $k-1$, as there is one less spot and one less person to take. I have tried to make sense of this in several ways but couldn't - such as the interpretation of "you add another spot when you multiply by $n$". It is quite easy to prove the statement so I am left wondering: how do I make sense of this result? Sorry if this isn't the standard mathematical proof question, but I feel like we could all benefit from some intuition regarding combinations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can see the probability of the particular person being selected in the team is $k/n$ because you can imagine that you line up the $n$ people in a row randomly and the first $k$ in the line get selected. Clearly this particular person is equally likely to be placed in any of the $n$ spots and there are $k$ favourable spots to be selected into the team, so the probability in question is $k/n$.

Comment: How about $n\binom{n-1}{k-1}=k\binom{n}{k}$ ... On LHS you pick a team leader from all students, then pick $k-1$ others from the remaining to form a team of $k$. On RHS you form the team first then pick a leader among the team member.

Comment: yes you mean $k/n$.  Say there are $n$ balls in a bag and $k$ of them are red, the rest green.  You ask: if i pick one ball from the bag, what are the chances it is red? That's easy it's $k/n$.  But now think of the act of picking one ball out of the bag as *leaving* $n-1$ balls IN the bag.  So the question of whether the ball you picked is red can be rephrased as what are the chances there are $k-1$ red and $n-k$ green balls LEFT in the bag after picking one?  That probability is the number of combinations of $k-1$ red balls out of $n-1$ divided by the number of total combos $n\choose k$.